# How do I parse a 3D JSON array in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array, json

```
my $test = '{
   "name":"Tony",
   "body":[ {
             "arms":["hands:fingers", "muscles:biceps"],
             "stomach":["abs:sixpack", "noabs:onepack"]
             },
             {
             "arms":["fingers:nails", "knuckles:sharp"],
             "stomach":["abs:gut", "noabs:liquor"]
          }]
}';
```

I'm trying this and it isn't working:

```
my $decoded = decode_json($test);
my @layer1 = @{ $decoded->{'body'} };
foreach ( @layer1 ) {
    @layer2 = $_->{$decoded->{'arms'} };
   foreach( @layer2 ) {
     print $_->{$decoded->{'hands'}} . "\n";
   }
}
```

I expect the printout to be:  fingers
My final result goal is to do, "If abs is a sixpack, then print the word fingers to a file."  I'm trying to do this on a mass scale from a large JSON of course.

Comment: can you show here the result of $decoded

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: You use `$decoded` in the inner loops, but at this point you should only deal with subelements of `$decoded`. Also it does not look like the value of "arms" is a hash, so you cannot write something like `$...->{'arms'}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you had turned on `use strict` and `use warnings`, which you should always do, you would have gotten a bunch of fatal errors about undeclared variables. Let's fix those first:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $test='{
   "name":"Tony",
   "body":[ {
             "arms":["hands:fingers", "muscles:biceps"],
             "stomach":["abs:sixpack", "noabs:onepack"]
             },
             {
             "arms":["fingers:nails", "knuckles:sharp"],
             "stomach":["abs:gut", "noabs:liquor"]
          }]
}';

my $decoded = decode_json($test);
my @layer1 = @{ $decoded->{'body'} };
foreach ( @layer1 ) {
   my @layer2 = $_->{$decoded->{'arms'} };
   foreach( @layer2 ) {
     print $_->{$decoded->{'hands'}} . "\n";
   }
}
```

Now, at least the code will compile under `use strict`. But it emits a bunch of warnings:

```
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at js.pl line 21.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at js.pl line 23.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at js.pl line 23.

Use of uninitialized value in hash element at js.pl line 21.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at js.pl line 23.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at js.pl line 23.
```

These warnings are useful information! What a useful tool `use warnings` is!

Let's look at the first one: *Use of uninitialized value in hash element at js.pl line 21.*

Line 21 is:

```
my @layer2 = $_->{$decoded->{'arms'} };
```

In this loop, `$_` is set to each element of the outer array, (`@{ $decoded->{body} }`). Each element of that array is a hash reference. What you're doing is trying to use the key `arms` in the *first level* of the hash as a key into the hash pointed to by the elements in the array. That key doesn't exist in those hashes, which is why you get the warnings about uninitialized values.

To get what we want, we just need

```
my @layer2 = @{ $_->{arms} };
```

Now the third layer is more complicated; it's an array of colon-delimited strings, not an array of hashes. In that loop we can just throw away the strings we don't want until we find `hands`

```
foreach( @layer2 ) { 
    next unless /^hands:/;
    my ( $thing, $other_thing ) = split /:/, $_;
    print $other_thing, "\n";
}
```

Here's the fixed script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $test='{
   "name":"Tony",
   "body":[ {
             "arms":["hands:fingers", "muscles:biceps"],
             "stomach":["abs:sixpack", "noabs:onepack"]
             },
             {
             "arms":["fingers:nails", "knuckles:sharp"],
             "stomach":["abs:gut", "noabs:liquor"]
          }]
}';

my $decoded = decode_json($test);
my @layer1 = @{ $decoded->{'body'} };
foreach ( @layer1 ) {
    my @layer2 = @{ $_->{arms} };
    foreach( @layer2 ) {
        next unless /^hands:/;
        my ( $thing, $other_thing ) = split /:/, $_;
        print $other_thing, "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fingers
```

For more on working with complex structures in Perl, see the following:

- [Perl references tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [Perl data structures cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [Perl references reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Read them, read them again, then write code. Then read them again.